# Trying to classify face images using scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn

I am trying to study unsupervised learning from face images using scikit-learn.
But I need some help on extracting features from images.
First of all, how can I make feature vectors for scikit-learn?? Can I use dictVectorizer, or feature hashing?? In order to make some pattern recognition system, features must be extracted from data if I understood correctly. So how can I extract features using built functions in scikit-learn?? I have been reading tutorials on website but all they do is show examples I think.

What I am trying to do is extracting features from images using SURF implemented in opencv python and vectorize them so that I can use function implemented in scikit-learn.
However, since the opencv function returns keypoints from each image, I do not know how I can organize these keypoints and make feature vectors in scikit-learn.
Or if there is nice method extracting features from an image and use them in scikit-learn, it would be nice.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Typically, you want to create a flattened 2D matrix X of size (n_samples, height * width). For images, one of the simplest ways is to do something like [shown here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/face_recognition.html) using eigendecomposition.

```
# (Assume faces is (100, 32, 32) and represents 100 images which are 32 by 32 each)
X = faces.reshape(faces.shape[0], faces.shape[1] * faces.shape[2])
```

If you generate SURF or SIFT or (another feature extraction algorithm) features, you could create a new 2D matrix which is (n_samples, height * width) of all zeros, then encode the keypoints as 1 in the flattened space by taking the keypoint coordinate and multiplying the X and Y values. You would do this for each *coord*, for *i* in *n_samples* images.

```
SIFT_X = np.zeros(faces.shape[0], faces.shape[1] * faces.shape[2])

# Assume coord is 1 keypoint from SIFT, represented as a tuple of (X, Y)
flat_coord = coord[0] * coord[1]
SIFT_X[i, flat_coord] = 1.
```

You could either use the keypoints directly as above, or get fancy and use the keypoints as a mask (with some acceptance region) on top of the original image. An easy way to check that the keypointing is working and that your coordinate systems are matching would be to use plt.scatter()

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
im = X[0, :].reshape(32, 32)
sift_feat = SIFT_X[0, :].reshape(32, 32)
sift_coord = np.where(sift_feat == 1)
plt.imshow(im)
plt.scatter(sift_coord[0], sift_coord[1])
plt.show()
```

Personally, I would start with the PCA/SVD method and work up to using SIFT/SURF etc. from there.